Firebase realtime rules - not working on child
Building a Firebase Realtime database with auth - but I
can't even get this started - returns permission denied
{
  "rules": {
    "forms": {
      "$formid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}

ultimately I'd like to apply a rule like such
{
  "rules": {
    "forms": {
      "$formid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == data.child('userId').val()",
        ".write": "auth.uid != 'null'"
      }
    }
  }
}

Data is formatted
forms

$formId (eg -Nan39eo)

userId



Console logging when rules are changed at the root to true returns that my authid is the same as the formId.userId

Please edit your question (there's a small edit link under it for that purpose) to add the minimal code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem against the first rules. --- For the second rules, make sure you read https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters

I think I realise now that I need to reformat my data, to store entries under the userId. As I've read docs and realise now rules can't filter. So to access the userId currently the user needs to have access to all form children. If I move the userId as the child of forms I can access /forms/$childId in my request and match it to auth.id successfully.
